# how to reload a javascript asset in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the code below (it's in my twig file) to attach a javascript file specific to this template.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset("bundles/myappmybundle/js/jobs.js") }}"></script>
```

It is working fine **EXCEPT** the fact even if I made changes to the javascript file, somehow my browser (firefox with firebug) is still loading a previous version.

I've tried:

1. clearing cache via php app/console
2. rm -rf app/cache/*

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Michael's answer is correct, but if you do not want to make symlinks, just edit the file directly in /web/bundles/ and when you have a state that you want to keep, copy the file into the described src/YourBundle/Resources/public folder.

Answer (score 1):

It might be in two cases:

- Your browser cached this js for you. Try to clear cache of your browser
- You installed assets once with `hard-copy` option (by default). And after you changed files you didn't update your assets with `php app/console assets:install`.

To make your assets always synced with your bundle's code you can just run in CLI:

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink
```

It will create symlink to `src/YourBundle/Resources/public` folder in the `/web/bundles/`

Comment: I used the symlink option so that's probably not it. I'll clearing the cache.